# Whenever this server side validation checks, it returns false even when i enter correct password

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation, passwords

This is the code. abc_university is my database name.

```
<?php
include('connectionfile.php');
$query=("select username,password from professor where username='$_POST[username]'AND password='$_POST[password]'");
$result=MYSQL_QUERY($query);
$number = abc_university_numrows($result);
if($number ==0)
{
    abc_university_close($id_link);
    header("Location:InvalidUser.php"); 
}
else if($number ==1)
{
    $user=$_POST['username'];
    $pwd=$_POST['password'];
    session_start();
    session_register("user");
    if(!isset($_POST['user']))
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $prof_email_id;
                $_SESSION['pwd'] = $prof_pwd;
            }
    abc_university_close($id_link);
    header("Location:UserPage.php");    
}
else
{
    abc_university_close($id_link);
    header("Location:InvalidUser.php"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Its nice you want to show us your code - but do you have a question?

Comment: Not really a direct answer to your question, but I would like to strongly discourage you from doing this: `username='$_POST[username]'` - it creates a very serious SQL injection venerability.  You should also ideally call `exit();` after your redirects, again for security reasons, and it looks like you're not hashing your passwords.

Comment: Lots of problems here. 1. You're open to SQL injection. 2. You're using mysql_* instead of mysqli_*. 3. `echo $query;` and make sure your query runs against your database directly.

Comment: @hemalshah plz show the connectionfile. your code is not clear

Comment: Additionally to mkaatman's list of problems it's important to know, that passwords should not be stored plaintext, instead they should be hashed with a slow hash function like BCrypt. Without showing more of your code, especially the function `abc_university_numrows()`, it is very difficult to give advice. Did you check, whether the password is stored correctly in the database, and what exactly does not work (does the redirect call the correct page)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all have you defined a function named `abc_university_numrows();` or shouldn't you be using `mysql_num_rows()` instead.

Also why dont you move to `mysqli` as mysql is now deprecated.